# c++ Assembler File Reading

Tags: c++, assembly, getline

I am currently working on an SIC/XE assembler in C++. How should I go about reading SIC/XE code from a text file?

(LABEL - OPCODE - OPERAND)

```
COPY    START   0   
FIRST   STL RETADR  
    LDB #LENGTH
```

How would I get getline() to adapt to the 3rd line where there is no "label"? (Tabbed space)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read a line at a time, and parse the different components of each line. You can check if the line starts with a "whitespace" (`isspace(line[0])`), in which case it doesn't have a label [assuming that is the rule for labels, of course!]

(Or you can, of course, parse individual characters into tokens, in the same way that a free-form compiler like a C/C++ compiler works, but since the format looks like it's rather simple, it' would be easier to read a line at a time and just reject the whole thing with some suitable error if it's not "right")